# NoCaptcha in SalesForce Web to Lead

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, umbraco, recaptcha

I've got an legacy Umbraco ASP.NET site (v4.7) which I've been requested to place a SalesForce web to sales form on it. I've done this and all is well apart from the amount of spam that's getting through.

So I'm trying to use the Google NoCaptcha widget which I've successfully placed on the form but I don't know how to validate the response. All of the examples I've searched are using PHP cURL method which I cannot use.

To further complicate things the site is compiled and I've don't have access to the source files so I can't create any controls/classes, etc. in the solution.

Is it possible to validate the recaptcha response using only the 'client' (javascript for example) with no back end processing done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 1):

set the `enabled` property of the button to `false`.

```
<asp:button id="btnName" enabled="false" text="submit" />
```

and then on the recaptcha container:

```
<div id="asd" class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="EnableButton" data-expired-callback="DisableButton" data-sitekey="your-site-key">
</div>
```

where `data-callback` and `data-expired-callback` are events of the widget.

data-callback:

> invoked after a successful captcha

data-expired-callback:

> invoked when session times out.

where `EnableButton` and `DisableButton` are javascript functions which does exactly what they say they do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var DisableButton = function () {
            alert("Confirmation Expired. Please Answer Recaptcha.");
            document.getElementById('<%=btnName.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
            grecaptcha.reset();
        };
        var EnableButton = function () {
            document.getElementById('<%=btnName.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        };
</script>
```

but it is really recommended to still verify it on server-side.

hope it helps..

Comment: Hiya, cheers for that, I shall give that a whirl and report back :)

Comment: Doing it now mate. Works gone mental for the last week.

Comment: Hi Mate,

No luck I'm afraid (it seems the validation functions aren't firing) this is what I've done.

On the captcha container
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="EnableButton" data-expired-callback="DisableButton" data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>

On the button
<input id="submitbutton" disabled="true" class="contourButton contourNext contourSubmit" type="submit" name="submit">

And I've included the script block. 

But the script functions don't appear to be being fired :(

Comment: Hiya,

Actually changing             document.getElementById('#submitbutton').disabled = false;

To 
$('#submitbutton').prop("disabled", false);

Seems to have done it :)

Comment: @SxChoc that's great. please accept as answer if it helped you. or upvote if you like.. unfortunately, i still dont have the privilege to upvote your question, not enough rep..